# как вывести только часы datetime

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

нужно сравнивать время и определять утро, день, вечер. Можно использовать только часы. Не могу вывести точнее то могу но сравнить не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например:

```
import datetime

hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
if hour < 10:
    print('С добрым утром!')
```

Читайте [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), там всё это есть.

Comment: Намечается тенденция по созданию вопросов для каждого атрибута datetime) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1337433

Comment: спасибо помогло!!

Comment: @ДамирБурлаков Но всё-таки учитесь читать документацию, там всё есть )

Comment: да я читал но все же не получилось скорее всего плохо читал)

Comment: @ДамирБурлаков Родная питоновская дока по библиотекам, конечно, большая и перегруженная информацией, там бывает непросто что-то найти без опыта, это да.